# Remove and Merge issue @ElementCollection JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using jpa and creating sql independently whithout autogenerate sql,
have three tables village, population and village_population where village_population holds mapping.

My entity mapping is something like this

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "village_population", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "village_id"), 
            uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"village_id","population_id"}))    
@Column(name = "population_id")        
private final Set<String> populationIds = new HashSet<String>();
```

The merge when adding child is working fine but update is not working, when looking at sql logs it just shows update query and insert query for village table and insert query for collection table (village_population) but not running update query on village_population

Comment: No idea what is "creating sql independently without autogenerate sql"

Comment: @NeilStockton I mean to say I am not using auto-generated schema and creating sqls manually, thanks